# Convert a File[ ] to String [ ]

Tags: java, arrays, file, type-conversion

**Problem:** Convert a File[ ] to String [ ]

```
File[] objectArray=getXMLFiles(new File("C:\\some-path"));
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
```

I do understand this exception is coming because i am directly copying the file Object to String array.But can someone help me with converting my objectArray to stringArray.Please help me a easy way to convert this.

**Requirement:**
I want that file array elements to be picked one by one so that 1 by 1 will get location of the file and will process in loop.Sample below.`aAL and cAL is arraylist.`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     String fp=stringArray(i); //String array required to do this.
     String accountNum=aAL.get(i).toString();
     String custId=cAL.get(i).toString();
    Runnable worker = new XMLMultithreading(fp,anum,cid);
    executor.execute(worker);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your method `getXMLFiles()` calls `File.listFiles()`. If so, consider using `File.list()` instead.

Comment: @ponomandr: Missed that.Yes its calling File.ListFiles()

Comment: @user3930361::Do remember if you are using any fileobject.isFile() to check if it is a valid file.It won't work in that case if File.list().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a File to String, cause a File is not a String.

However File has a few methods (getName(), getAbsolutePath()) that return a String.

So you can do :

```
String[] stringArray = new String[objectArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) stringArray[i] = objectArray[i].getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: I guess this solves the purpose.But the best would be going as per the ponomandr's comment above,if only array of string is required at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
File[] files =getXMLFiles(new File("C:\\some-path"));
fileArray = new String[files.length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i){
fileArray[i] = files[i].getName();
}
```